# Attempt to reference a sheet yields "Run Time Error 1004"

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I'm just trying to select a column so that I can change the date format.  I have no idea why, but my code is giving me a huge issue anytime I try to reference the sheet the column is in.  But what I don't understand is that many times earlier in my code I successfully reference the sheet with no issues.

Has anyone seen this?
Did VBA just forget about me defining and setting my variable?

Here's an example of my code:

```
Dim wbPrescrub As Workbook, wsPrescrub As Worksheet
Set wbPrescrub = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPrescrub = wbPrescrub.Sheets("PreScrub")
wsPrescrub.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=(""), _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues
wsPrescrub.Range("E2:E" & pslastRow).SpecialCells    (xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

wsPrescrub.AutoFilterMode = False


wsPrescrub.Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit



wsPrescrub.Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

I included lines of my code which worked fine,  it is the last two lines that are giving me trouble.  I cannot get past the `wsPrescrub.Columns` line.  If I run the code without referencing the sheet it works perfectly fine on the ActiveSheet and correctly selects the column and format.  But the second I add in what sheet to look at I get:

> Run Time Error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Try to combine the last two lines into a single one: `wsPrescrub.Columns("F:F").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: Excellent! That worked, I'm still not sure why it didn't work my way, but it's fine by me.  Thank you!

Comment: Probably worksheet `PreScrub` was not active, that is why you couldn't select any range from it. But actually, it is bad practice to select ranges and manipulate on `Selection` instead of manipulating directly on ranges.

Comment: Shouldn't you `.AutoFit` *after* changing the number format?

Comment: @Jeeped is right, changing format will change the width of the column, so you should move `.AutoFit` at the end of the code.